Mitigating Digital Noise in ADC Data Collection with Spartan-6 FPGA
We’re facing an issue with digital noise while collecting ADC data on an FPGA-based system. Here’s our setup and the details:
We’re using an FPGA from the Spartan-6 family (specifically the XC6SLX9 model) to collect and process ADC data. The data collected from the ADC is stored in SDRAM, and within the FPGA, we use summing and averaging techniques to reduce noise from the signal. However, we’re observing unwanted digital noise appearing in our ADC data.
For instance, as shown in the image below, there is a noticeable noise spike around the 5000th data point. This spike occurs when we toggle a pin on the FPGA for certain operations.

Additionally, in the image below, there is noise associated with the SDRAM logic itself, which is introduced by the data writing/reading processes.

We’ve tried a couple of approaches to mitigate this noise:

Randomizing the SDRAM logic’s access pattern – By varying the SDRAM’s access location, we managed to reduce some of the noise, but this method has limitations and doesn’t fully resolve the issue.
Postponing the SDRAM access phase – Delaying the SDRAM phase reduces the noise more effectively, but it also increases our system’s processing time, which is not ideal.

Next image shows the correct signal using second approch:

Unfortunately, redesigning the board layout to better isolate signals or reduce interference isn’t feasible due to budget constraints.
Question: Is there any method to further reduce or eliminate the noise in our ADC data by adjusting the FPGA’s settings or configurations? Specifically, are there known techniques or best practices within the Spartan-6 family or for SDRAM interfaces that might help mitigate this noise without requiring physical changes to the board?
schematic and layout added:


Next images show the top layer and the power plane layouts.Ground plane is solid everywhere:



EDIT: To simplify the issue we removed the SDRAM logic and collected data in the following architecture which is part of our data acquisition algorithm. The first group consists of 52 data points, and the second group consists of 128 data points. The ADC operates at 40 MHz, while the memory operates at 120 MHz, so our first FIFO is working with a mixed clock setup (40 MHz to 120 MHz). The repetitive noise pattern in the collected data is still obvious. Notably, the pattern length aligns with our batch size, totaling 180 points (128 + 52). Changing the batch sizes also alters the pattern size, suggesting a link between batch size and noise pattern.



In another experiment, each corresponding point is collected and added together using a simple register, and here is the true waveform.


Why using just FIFO should affect the data while there are no other rapid switching logic?

Are you able to show the schematic and layout for the board? Without knowing where the interference is being injected (e.g. ADC power supply, ADC reference voltage, ADC input) difficult to give mitigation techniques.

@ChesterGillon schematics and layouts for the board are added.

You have given a of information, but there is a lot you left out. What is the ADC, and how fast are you clocking it? How are you driving VIN+ and VIN-, and have you looked at them with a scope to determine whether the problem appears there? There appears to be no isolation of ground currents at all; how are the various power rails isolated from each other? Where does power enter the board?

@DaveTweed  ADC is an AD9236, It works with a 40 MHz oscillator. The 40 MHz is going into the FPGA for sampling the input data. We can't see the noise with a scope because it is very weak. We are adding the input data with each other for denoising purpose then it appears.


Unfortunately, redesigning the board layout to better isolate signals or reduce interference isn’t feasible due to budget constraints.

I'm sorry to say that but the reason you even have to ask the question is that the layout is borked and has to be redone. No way around that. Did you expect the layout to work on first try? It usually doesn't go that way unless you've done several similar layouts before. You have a serious coupling between the digital side currents and the ADC.
As long as you think you can "salvage" the layout, you'll not fix this. You've clearly demonstrated that the circuit doesn't work as-is, and layout is a part of the circuit. You likely won't fix it merely by changing passive component values.


Remove all decoupling caps under the FPGA. Draw a line on the bottom side of the board, going through the centers of all the decoupling capacitors under the FPGA. This line will be closed and look roughly like a square. Then make a cut along this square, so that you'll isolate a blue subplane under the FPGA. Inspect the cut under microscope to make sure it's free of conductive debris. Then reinstall the capacitors. This will help keep a part of the capacitor return currents away from rest of the board.

Ensure you're not coupling noise to the reference. Connect a battery-derived reference voltage directly to the ADC, leaving the decoupling network, so that the only connection between the reference and the rest of the circuit will be via ground. Compare noise before and after this change.

Ensure that you're not coupling noise to the signal source. The ADC has a differential input. So you can just short it and connect it to common mode. Then see what you measure. If the noise goes away, then you'll know that it was coupled to the signal source.


This should be hopefully enough to ensure that the analog signal you're measuring is clean - and that signal really consists of both the reference and the "input".

Then you can keep increasing the ADC output isolation resistor network value until you start getting junk from the ADC, then back off a bit to restore the signals. If the noise is roughly of the same amplitude as before the change, then you'll know it's not the problem with coupling via the digital bus.

Another way of checking this is to add digital isolators between the ADC and the FPGA. If they change nothing much, then currents on the ground plane are the problem.


This may be the case where you really want to place the ADC and its power supplies on a separate sub-ground-plane, and only connect it to the rest of the plane right under the resistor networks/digital isolators. This would help with keeping all of the FPGA's and SDRAM's currents outside of the ADC and source signal area.

Thanks for your time and apologize for asking another similar question. More clarification was added to this question 1.We removed all the caps and created an isolated subplane under the FPGA so the return current path was just through the second layer which is a solid ground plane, but this didn't solve the issue.2. A battery-generated voltage reference using an LDO without the decoupling network also did not help.3.We tested without giving any input to the ADC or they were shorted and the pattern still exists and increasing the output resistor network did not change much the noise amplitude.

To simplify the situation we did another experiment using just FIFOs and its description is added to the question. We also have another setup where the FPGA board and the ADC board are separated and just connected with a coaxial cable for giving a clock from the FPGA to the ADC and ribbon cable for the data BUS. So they have separated grounds and the grounds are connected just with the coax cable shield but the problem still exists.
